# Allow write to one child in Realtime Firebase database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

In a Realtime Firebase database there are a lot off Childs

And in those Childs the are some more.

What rule's do i add so Read = true
Butt **only write** to the child "Pupil" and everything in that child

```
   "rules": 
{
".read": true,
".write": false
}
"Pupil": 
 {
  ".read": true,
  ".write": true
 }
}
```

I am missing a  Expected ',' or '}'.

Comment: Use any json formatter: like: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/
It will help you to understand what you're missing to in it to be json file in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The security rules for the Firebase Realtime Database as in JSON format, and what you have is not valid JSON. In fact, it's not even close.

I highly recommend using a tool that can show you whether your code is valid JSON (a quick search can help you find one of these).

The closest valid JSON equivalent to what you have seems to be:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": false
  },
  "Pupil": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

While this is now valid JSON, it is not a valid set of security rules, as you can only have one top-level event (names `rules`) in security rules, and the rest of your rules needs to be under that.

---

To make it into valid security rules, nest the `Pupil` node under the top-level `rules`:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": false,
    "Pupil": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": true
    }
  }
}
```

So you should be able to save the above in the Firebase console without an error.

---

You can simplify this a bit to:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    "Pupil": {
      ".write": true
    }
  }
}
```

The top-level read permission is automatically inherited by all nodes under the root. And by default there is no permission, so the `".write": false` on the root is implied here.